# How do I find all the records regardless of case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What can i do you find a case insensitive search

```
>> Band.find_by_name("metallica")
=> nil
>> Band.find_by_name("Metallica")
=> #<Band id: 3, name: "Metallica", created_at: "2010-10-03 01:17:24", updated_at: "2010-10-03 01:17:24", user_id: "4">
```

I need to find the record in both cases...any suggestions?

Comment: Totally depends on what type of database you're using. MySQL will perform case-insensitive search by default; SQLite and PostegreSQL will not. If you're on SQLite for development and plan to deploy to MySQL, though, then it'll only be an issue on your development box, unless you decide to do MySQL on your dev box for consistency.

Comment: we are developing a product.. And our different clients want to go with diff databases.. We want to support our application to different databases like oracle,db2,mysql,postgress ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Band.find(:all, :conditions => ['name = lower(?)', band_name.downcase])
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3, you could do

```
band_name = 'Metallica'
Band.where('LOWER(name) = ?', band_name.downcase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to put in some raw sql for this.

```
Band.find :conditions => ['name ILIKE ?', 'metallica'] #if you are using postgres...
```